# Issue with changing graphics card and nvopencl.dll. Blender immediately crashes

Tags: drivers

So I changed my graphics card from an NVidia graphics card (NVidia Geforce 430)  to an AMD graphics card (ASUS STRIX R7 370). But now when I start Blender I get an error message that says:

> C:\Windows\System32\nvopencl.dll is either not designed to run on
>   Windows or it contains an error. Try installing the program again.
>   Error status 0xc000012f

I think the problem is that blender still thinks I am using an nvidia card.

I have tried to factory reset the settings and also I have reinstalled the lastest version of blender.

I have also updated my AMD drivers and as far as I know I have removed all the NVidia drivers (even in the Regedit).

I have also tried running the windows DLL Tool DICM, but that didn't help.

I am tempted to delete the file but I'm not sure if I should and also if I do delete the file, it seems like there are other dll in system32 that relate to nvidia, should I delete them too?

Thanks.

Comment: I found that running blender 2.71 has made it possible to launch. However I can't use cylces, and I think that this nvidia thing is the problem, so I still need a way to fix this.

Comment: Move the files to another location. That way if things break even more you can put them back. Also make sure your new video card meets Blender's hardware requirements.